# column headers in SAS datasets

Tags: sas

My supervisor sent me a SAS dataset. I opened it in SAS and found that the headers shown are long variable labels instead of variable names. How can I change the headers from variable labels to variable names? I  know how to get variable names by 'proc contents' procedure, but I do not know how to let SAS display a dataset with variable names whenever I open the dataset in SAS.

Comment: What SAS client do you use? If you are in SAS EG, SAS DI, etc, there are different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple menu option under "View":
[image]

If you want to force SAS to ALWAYS default to NAMES, you need to change a SAS Explorer setting. Another menu option, **starting with the Explorer window active**:
[image]

And then edit the "members" > "table" > "open" instruction to specify "names" rather than labels:
[image]

For further details, refer to SAS documentation for the [Windowing Environment](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1otloofcbwkpnn1sfkrhh9zjl74.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The fast and dirty way is to submit "options nolabel;", meaning that SAS will generally ignore labels. You can always switch back by submitting "options label;"